# ¿Cómo pasar una variable string por url desde Ajax?

Tags: ajax, url

Tengo este codigo  en el que paso por url una variable, pero necesito pasar otra tipo string y por alguna razon no me funciona.

```
$('#formulario').load('php/form.php?idHis='+data_form['id']);
```

Ademas de data_form['id'], me gustaría poder pasar otra variable tipo string pero no se muy bien como.

Este es el codigo:

```
tipo='1';
 $('#addFact').load('php/frm_adFactura.php?id='+idHis+'&tipo='+tipo);
```

Si la variable tipo es 1 funciona bien, si la variable tipo le pongo 'H', da un error y dice que H no esta definida. Aqui pongo como recojo la variable.

```
<?php
id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>;
tipo=<?php echo $_GET['tipo'];?>;
?>
```

Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes separar cada variable a enviar con `&` y seguir concatenando con `+` como lo has hecho.

Edito: debido a que cuando recibes la variable `tipo` está llega `H` lo que no se puede interpretar, por lo que debes concatenar también las comillas.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: H is not defined.

Puedes concatenar las comillas en la url o cuando lo recibes con el `GET`

1 - En la url:

```
$('#formulario').load('php/frm_adFactura.php?id='+idHis+'&tipo='+'"'+tipo+'");
```

2 - En el Get

```
tipo=<?php echo "'".$_GET['tipo']."'";?>;
```

---

Ejemplo donde se ve que la variable tipo va como `H`

```js
var idHis = 12;
var tipo = 'H';  //forma1
var tipo2 = "\'H\'";  //forma2
console.info("php/frm_adFactura.php?id="+idHis+"&tipo="+"'"+tipo+"'"); //funciona forma 1
console.log("php/frm_adFactura.php?id="+idHis+"&tipo="+tipo2); //funciona forma 2
console.error("php/frm_adFactura.php?id="+idHis+"&tipo="+tipo);
```

Comment: Muy Buenas, Gracias por Contestar, he editado la pregunta  y   he puesto el código que estoy usando para ver la razón del problema. Lo he hecho como me ha indicado pero sigue sin funcionar. Un saludo

Comment: @LorenzoMartín en este caso, podrías colocar mas código? De ser posible también en que linea te sale el error..

Comment: Muy buenas, este es el error que me sale en consola.                     Uncaught ReferenceError: H is not defined.  Si en vez de tipo='H'; pongo tipo='1'; funciona bien.. Gracias .

Comment: @LorenzoMartín revisa, porque edite la respuesta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, llevaba mucho tiempo con este tema y no sabia como sollucionarlo. Un saludo